# Python - unicodedata.normalization is missing certain characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have data that has characters such as ɐ̀ and ʒ̇. I would like to write each character line by line into a file, so I'm doing

```
line = normalize('NFC', line.lower())
for char in line:
    file.write((char + '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
```

Although characters like ǧ end up getting written as a single character, characters like ɐ̀ and ʒ̇ still end up being written as two characters, like ʒ and ̇  , so the normalization function doesn't work. Is there any other way to combine these?

Comment: Do these characters exist as unique Unicode code points? "Normalization" does *not* equal "combine all characters into 1".

Comment: There are many compositions for Latin characters, but essentially none for IPA extensions. You are seeing a problem where none exists.